# How to refactor Android package name on Android Studio, by adding a section?

Tags: android

I have an android application, with a package name that I want to change to allow for an update to be published to Google Play

This is on Android Studio, and I want to change the name from `com.company.name` to `com.something.company.name` However I could not find any resources to add the extra `.something.`  to the package, only to rename existing parts.

Is there any method of doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You talking two separate things now. One is `packageId` which is [unique ID for your application](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id) (as used in Google Play). And another thing is [Java package name](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html). These two are not  related really and do not have to stay in sync.

To change the `packageId` just edit your Manifest file or go `Project Strucure` dialog (<kbd>F4</kbd>) then to `app` tab, and either edit `defaultConfig`'s `Application Id` or edit each flavour (`dev`, `prod` etc, accordingly), if you want Id to differ in each flavor.

[image]

Comment: I did this, however the Play Console gives me an error: Your APK or Android App Bundle needs to have the package name com.something.company.name

Answer (score 1):

If you need to change your base package name do the following:

1. Press Ctrl+Shift+R to open replace all window on Android Studio and replace all `com.company.name` to `com.something.company.name`.
2. Open `com` folder on your file explorer and create a folder named `something` and move `company` folder and all its contents to your new `something` folder.
3. Rebuild your project.

Answer (score 1):

1. Select a package you want to rename in Project Tree `src/main`
2. Press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> and select **Rename Package**
3. enter a new package name and press **Refactor** (or **Preview**)
4. Find `AndroidManifest.xml` and make sure the `package` attribute contains the updated value. You may need to edit this manually.
5. If you have `src/test` and `src/androidTest` directories and they are not renamed automatically, repeat the above steps for these directories.

Comment: When I do this, it opens up a dialog only to rename the "main" directory, it does not give the option to rename package

Comment: @AryanGulati sorry for the confusion. in the 1st step, select **a package** (located in main src root), but not **main** itself.